# No option being selected in <select>

Tags: jquery

I have a javascript function that populates a form using the option value of a select.  When the option is selected, it populates the fields and the other select ('selVehicleEditModel'), but doesn't select an option.

```
function displayEditVehicle() {
    var data = jQuery('#selVehicleEditList option:selected').val();
    var dataArray = data.split("|");
    jQuery('#inpVehicleId').val(dataArray[0]);
    jQuery('#selVehicleEditMake option[value="' + dataArray[4] + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
    jQuery('#inpVehicleEditVehicleId').val(dataArray[9]);
    jQuery('#inpVehicleEditColor').val(dataArray[7]);
    jQuery('#inpVehicleEditLicense').val(dataArray[8]);
    jQuery('#inpVehicleEditYear').val(dataArray[6]);

    //get all models for make from database
    updateVehicleEditModel();
    jQuery('#selVehicleEditModel option[value="' + dataArray[5] + '"]').attr("selected", "selected"); 
}
```

At first, I thought maybe there was a problem with the model (dataArray[5]) being blank or null or something else unexpected, so I put an alert in:

```
    updateVehicleEditModel();
    alert(dataArray[5]);
    jQuery('#selVehicleEditModel option[value="' + dataArray[5] + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
```

that confirmed that value was correct ("EXPLORER" in dataArray[5], "EXPLORER" in option value), but it also selected the proper option.  Took the alert out, and it's back to not selecting any option.

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: Does `jQuery('#selVehicleEditModel').val(dataArray[5]);` work for you? Sounds like a race condition where it doesn't know that the option exists unless it waits a bit (your `alert` causes some blocking).

Comment: As the above comment says, your `updateVehicleEditModel` function is making a database call to get the data. This is undoubtedly happening asynchronously. Without the alert, the next line executes before anything has populated.

Comment: @h2ooooooo and rockerest:  that's what I was thinking, but A) wasn't sure and B) couldn't think of a way to fix it.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an AJAX call in the `updateVehicleEditModel` function, then consider putting the next statements (the ones which are to be called after the data is received and/or uses the data that is received from the ajax call to execute anything) in the success callback of the AJAX call.

Comment: That did the trick.